# problem with class template

Tags: c++, templates

I have homework to do, but I'm not very familirized with class templates.

The task is:

> There's a major problem in the implementation of the following class. Can you spot it? How can you fix 
>   the problem? You can propose more than one solution, depending on the requirement specifications of 
>   the class.

```
    template <class T>
class Array
{
private:
    T *m_pData;
    unsigned int m_nSize;

public:
  Array(unsigned int nSize) : m_nSize(nSize)
  {
    if(m_nSize > 0)
      m_pData = new T[m_nSize];
  }

virtual ~Array()
  {
    if(m_pData != NULL)
      delete m_pData;
  }
bool Set(unsigned int nPos, const T& Value)
  {
    if(nPos < m_nSize)
    {
      m_pData[nPos] = Value;
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }

  T Get(unsigned int nPos)
  {
    if(nPos < m_nSize)
      return m_pData[nPos];
    else
      return T();
  }
};
```

As far as I'm concerned there is a memory leak. Do you spot some other problems? Hints are more welcome than precise answers ;)

Comment: There's no memory leak (since the memory is released by the destructor), but you're thinking along the right lines. There are at least three major problems, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Constructor - You need to set the value of m_pData in the event of nSize being 0
2. You can delete null pointers so the if statement is not required in the destructor. The delete should be delete[]

Comment: wow, the check before delete is so common at my workplace that I never noticed.  It's a minuscule performance thing, not a bug, but the question asked for `problems` so I guess it counts.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor: there's an `if` without an `else`.  Consider the consequences.
Make sure new[] is matched with delete[] and new with delete.
This violates the rule of 3 (or 5 with C++0x)

That's all I see.

Comment: if this is just homework, i doubt that c++0x problems will show up

Answer (score 1):

There's no copy constructor or assignment operator. This code will crash your program very quickly. That's the major flaw.

Making the destructor virtual is a strange decision. No obvious need or benefit to deriving from this class.

I would implement a swap method too.

Comment: 'Propose more than one solution', that's obviously referring to either the correct solution of implementing the copy constructor and assignment operator, or to the lazy solution of declaring them private.

Answer (score 0):

heres a few things, but i doubt that any of them are serious enough to be the correct answer:

1. the `get` function returns a value for invalid indexes. if `type T` were `int`s, and you used `get` with a too large of an index, the answer you would get would be 0. what if the values can be 0? how do you tell the difference between a `0` value and an invalid index value?
2. there is some extra code: you dont need the `else return`